# My first function is having a syntax error

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I am just getting into writing functions and I think I am a bit over my head.  The javascript console is stating

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#**insert the jsfiddle url**"

Since I don't have enough reputation I cannot post two links, but where "insert the jsfiddle url" is the jsfiddles url, it becomes the url of any site I run this code on.

Here is the code is the code for it:

```
   function menuclick(menuitem, menucontent) {
   $('"#' + menuitem + '"').click(function() {
      $('#cssmenu').hide();
      $('"#' + menucontent + '"').show();
      $('#goback').show();
   })
};


      menuclick(aboutlink, aboutcontainer);
```

[Here is the link to a jsfiddle of it.](http://jsfiddle.net/gqwugdf3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `$('"#' + menuitem + '"')` is **wrong**.

When `menuitem = "hello"`, the above code becomes `$('"#hello"')` which is **NOT** what you want.

You want `$('#' + menuitem)` which results in `$('#hello')` when `menuitem = "hello"`

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/gqwugdf3/1/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
$('#aboutcontainer').hide();
$('#goback').hide();

function menuclick(menuitem, menucontent) {
  $('#' + menuitem).click(function() {
    $('#cssmenu').hide();
    $('#' + menucontent).show();
    $('#goback').show();
  })
};


menuclick('aboutlink', 'aboutcontainer');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssmenu"><a href="#" id="aboutlink">About</a>
</div>
<div id="aboutcontainer">djdsidjkjd
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<div id="goback">Go back</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of errors and problems. Here you are your fiddle working:

http://jsfiddle.net/gqwugdf3/2/

What I do:

Remove unnecesary double quotes :

```
 $('"#' + menuitem + '"') //incorrect
 $('#' + menuitem) // correct
```

put quotes in calling

```
  menuclick('aboutlink', 'aboutcontainer');
```